# Video playback disappears after a few seconds

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to play a video within a UIView using MPMoviePlayerController.
After pressing a UIButton, the video appears and starts playing.
Unfortunately after 3-4 seconds, the video gets black, the audio is still playing.
Any ideas?
Thanks for all your time.

(Using Xcode 4.2.1)

```
    -(void) playMovieButtonPressed:(UIButton*) button{

        NSString* video = @"testmovie.m4v";

        NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[video stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[video pathExtension]];
        NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
        MPMoviePlayerController* player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                   object:player];  

        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        [player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 400, 300, 200)];
        [self.view addSubview:player.view];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];  
    }

- (void) moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"videoviewcontroller complete:  %@", notification);

    MPMoviePlayerController *mymoviePlayerController = [notification object];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                  object:mymoviePlayerController];  
}
```

Comment: as ridiculous as this may sound, have you tried another video.  My working code is almost identical.. all my extension types are mp4 though, and I'm not using player.movieSourceType

Comment: Thx for replying. Yeah, sure. I´ve tested other videos, other formats, other source types - no luck. I´ve also tested it in a new fresh Project with just one button - exactly the same problem. Which Xcode version do you have installed?

Comment: I convert my videos all with Handbrake and the iPad profile. What do you use? Thanks for sharing the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I´ve talked to an Apple Engineer. The solution is that the player would have to be an **instance variable or property of the view controller**. So its still accessible when view was being torn down.

```
-(void) playMovieButtonPressed:(UIButton*) button{

        NSString* video = @"testmovie.m4v";

        NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[video stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[video pathExtension]];
        NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
        self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 

// .....
}
```

Comment: After trying many solutions, this turned to be the correct one!